# How to read NIFTI(.nii) data and write to excel sheet in MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, file-read, nifti

I am new to statistical analysis of diffusion tensor imaging data. following is my query

I have NIFTI (`.nii`) files of 3 subjects (subj_02, subj_03, subj_10)
and performing 3 tasks (task_1,task_2,task_3). I have selected 5
different cortical target regions (target_02, target_04, target_06,
target_08, target_10) to study neural pathways between brainstem and
cortex.

I have stored the results in following format

`task/subj_*/target_*/fdt_paths.nii.gz`

I would like to perform some data analysis with the acquired NIFTI (`.nii`)
files, for which I would like to read the data from generated
results( NIFTI files )  and export results into an excel-table as
per `Task/Subject/Target`.

## Question:

I am currently using `MATLAB-SPM8` for reading the NIFTI files , could
you please let me know some hints to efficiently read the NIFTI
files and export the data to excel-sheets?

Comment: Just a comment: SPM8 is old now. Consider using SPM12. By the way, show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: How to upgrade from SPM8 to SPM12 ?. I just tried usual method to read the file in matlab  datadir = '/data/DTI';
fname = 'task_01/subj_02/target_02/fdt_paths.nii.gz';
Data2Read = fullfile(datadir,fname);